# Why ausearch does not find matches for SYSTEM_BOOT and SYSTEM_SHUTDOWN?

Tags: audit, linux-audit

I ask myself why I get no matches when I search for SYSTEM_BOOT or SYSTEM_SHUTDOWN.

```
ausearch -m SYSTEM_BOOT
ausearch -m SYSTEM_SHUTDOWN
```

To be sure that events are not getting lost during booting I added the kernel parameters "audit=1 audit_backlog_limit=320". This should have at least an effect on SYSTEM_BOOT. But it has not.
What may be the reason? Must I apply a certain rule?

Linux = openSUSE Leap 42.2